# Twitter API Email not getting

Tags: node.js, angular, twitter, satellizer

I am using the following code to get email after `twitter` login

```
    var requestTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
    var accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
    var profileUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true';

    var accessTokenOauth = {
            consumer_key: authConf.TWITTER_KEY,
            consumer_secret: authConf.TWITTER_SECRET,
            token: req.body.oauth_token,
            verifier: req.body.oauth_verifier
        };

        // Step 3. Exchange oauth token and oauth verifier for access token.

        request.post({ url: accessTokenUrl, oauth: accessTokenOauth }, function(err, response, accessToken) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            accessToken = qs.parse(accessToken);

            var profileOauth = {
                consumer_key: authConf.TWITTER_KEY,
                consumer_secret: authConf.TWITTER_SECRET,
                oauth_token: accessToken.oauth_token
            };


            // Step 4. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
            request.get({
                url: profileUrl,
                oauth: profileOauth,
                json: true
            }, function(err, response, profile) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("..........." + err)
                    return res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                if (profile) {
                   //Succes : Do something

              }
```

I am getting the access `token`. But in the step 4, I am getting an error as follows

> {"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this
>   resource","code":220}]}

I have tried refreshing the access `tokens` but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your app setting @ apps.twitter.com, under the `Permisions` tab, make sure that the `Request email addresses from users` checkbox is ticked as shown in the image, then update setting. You will need to regenerate access token for this new permission update to work.

[Twitter Dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev2gy.png)